# using patterns and matchers

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract Failed from this string `{"Login":"Failed"}` How do I set the pattern? Also could you provide an explanation. I referred to [this site](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/pattern_matcher.shtml#.UvsRPPmSyE8), but didn't understand what they meant by setting the pattern.  This is what I tried which failed:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(login);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Start by reading the javadoc of the classes you try to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Pattern `:\"(\\w+)\"`

Do like this

```
public static void main(String args[]){

        String login="{\"Login\":\"Failed\"}";
         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":\"(\\w+)\"");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(login);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string is in JSON format. An alternative to RegExp should be to parse it as JSON and then get the property "Login" from the JsonObject.

Recommended library: Google GSON.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have groups in your regex, group is an expression in parentheses. This task can also be solved with replaceAll

```
s = s.replaceAll(".+:\"(.+)\"}", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String line="{\"Login\":\"Failed\"};
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Failed");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }

or you can also use
String line="{\"Login\":\"Failed\"};
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":\"(\\w+)\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```